# Explicit unique Handle Modern c++

Tags: c++11

I am following along a course about modern C++. I get an error with explicit unique_handle function. It says m_value is unknown override specifier? I listed the value above it shows still be in variable space.

```
explicit unique_handle(pointer value = Traits::invalid()) throw()
        m_value {   value }
    {

    }
```

https://pastebin.com/MA4vnWR3

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a colon ':' before m_value, which denotes the start of the inializer list:

```
explicit unique_handle(pointer value = Traits::invalid()) throw()
   : m_value {   value }
{

}
```

Comment: That's what I thought but guy on pluralsight did no comma and compiled fine T_T